# Measure how good is the discrete approximation of continuous random process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, discrete-distributions

If continuous random random process approximated with discrete version - **how to measure how good is the approximation**?

One possible way is to compute and compare the moments. But for some probability distributions the second and greater moments could be infinite.

**Example:**

Continuous process defined over continuous random variables $C_{1},C_{2},...$ where $S_{0}=0\,\!$ and $S_{n}=\sum _{j=1}^{n}C_{j}$. Random variables taken from **continuous** distribution, let's say Pareto distribution.

It's approximated with discrete process over discrete random variables $D_{1},D_{2},...$ where $S_{0}=0\,\!$ and $S_{n}=\sum _{j=1}^{n}D_{j}$. Where random variables $D_{n}$ taken from **discrete** distribution and can take only $k$ possible values $V_{1}, V_{2}, ..., V_{k}$.

Let's say we choose $k = 5$, guessed somehow 5 discrete values and fitted the Markov Chain. This is our discrete approximation.

**Question 2**: How to find **optimal discrete values** for given $k$? If it helps the original process has Pareto distribution.